What settings I can use for Llama 3.1 to get the right answer?
I have Llama 3.1 8b running locally and if I ask a question LM Studio the answer is the right but if I try do it in my node app I having it wrong?
If documentation is required as part of an Increment, who creates it?
O The Developers.
O The technical writer.
O The Scrum Master.
O The Product Owner.
O Documentation is not a part of an Increment.

The correct answer is: The technical writer.
But if I try
  try {
    console.log("Making request to LLaMA model:")
    const response = await axios.post(
      llamaEndpoint,
    {
     prompt: result.data.text, // Input question
     // input: `Answer the question based solely on the given text. What is the right answer from given text?`,
     max_tokens: 100,
     temperature: 0.7,
     top_k: 50,
     no_stop_token: true,
     output: {
      return_full_text: false,
     },
   },
  { headers }
)

I will get it wrong like - Documentation is not a part of an Increment. or The Developers.
As I can see the LM Studio use the same just more tokens
    {
      "inputs": ["Text prompt"],
      "model_name": "l-LaMa 3.1",
      "max_tokens": 2048,
      "temperature": 0.7,
      "top_k": 50,
      "no_stop_token": true,
      "output": {
         "return_full_text": false
      }
   }

And the model is the same. How to fix any suggestions?

A model is only as good as the data it has been trained against.  Remember, this is only vectors of numbers at the end of the day. Very likely, this specific level of detail was not in the training data.  You can use reinforcement training techniques to 'advance the model's knowledge', or a RAG pipeline might be of use if the subject matter is specifically relating to a targeted area of expertise.

This is more of a training issue, rather than a settings issue.

@s3dev any suggestion what model (LM Studio) I can use for this task?

TBH, no idea mate, sorry.  We build our LLMs / chatbot apps and APIs completely bespoke, from the ground up.  None of this ‘magic box’ rubbish.
